# Remote Desktop Software with low latency for thin clients

Tags: rdp, vnc, latency, thin-client, audio

I'm currently using a thin client with the following specification:

[image]

I am searching for Remote Desktop software that will allow me to have a very low latency for audio quality on my thin clients. Currently, audio quality is poor. The desktop interface is good enough, but could be improved. **My main concern is the audio quality from the Remote Desktop**. I am running 5-10 thin clients on a server with:

- Core 2 Quad 2.4 GHz
- 4 GB RAM
- Over a 100 Mbit/s LAN

Are there any good recommendations out there for Remote Desktop Software for either Windows 7 or XP?

Currently my server is running Windows 7, but if you recommend a better solution that will require me to switch to XP that is also fine.

Comment: Are you after software for the client (the Android OS (?!)) or for that running on the server? Also I hope you server is slightly more powerful than 2.4Mhz...

Comment: thank you i forgot to mention that, software for windows xp or 7, i do have an i7 with 8 gig ram , but i want to test it on a low end server first so that we can use it for testing

Comment: But your Thin Clients run Android? Okay the server you're remoting to may support RemoteFX which enances video (and presumably audio) streaming so you could start looking at that. Then the clients connect to it using microsoft's remote desktop connection.

Comment: yes it can run independently using android or connect to the host server via Remote desktop.

Comment: `currently my server is running on windows 7` - No it's not. If it's running a client OS, it's not what most professionals would ever call a "server".

Comment: We don't do product recommendations, "design my [blah] for me," or suggest painfully unprofessional options like "better solution[s]" require switching to a decade old-OS.  Do it right, or don't do it at all... and from the looks of things, you're so far from doing it right, you're not going be able to get any help here.

Comment: @MDMarra i have a windows multipoint server 2012 on my i7 , i'm just trying to see if the core 2 quad will still be usable.

Comment: @HopelessN00b using old equipments rather than just trowing it away is more practical than buying a new one, if it still works it's then it's still usable, trying to find a solution for that can save a person a lot of money, but since you are so rich, don't do product endorsement and a very great and highly renowned "professional" then i'm so sorry that my post cast upon your presence since your so great and all. rather that bragging about something better just give a suggestion or don't give anything at all.

Comment: @MDMarra another professional, OK so it's not running a windows server , but still a server is the computer that host and process all the data, and technically that old computer does all of it. so if the definition of server is redefined by "you" then I'm so sorry o great and all knowing MDMarra all of those people that invented the word server must have been so unfortunate not meeting you.

Comment: @MDMarra a server can be considered anything that "serves" stuff to other machines... so yes, even though a win7 machine would not be considered "server-grade" in an enterprise market (like what both me and you work in), it can still be a "server" in it's own right.

Comment: @SnakeDoc Of course the academic definition of a server is a node on a network that provides services to other nodes. I was referring to the fact that this isn't a server that would (or should) be deployed in a professional setting, and as such is off topic for Server Fault. I should have been clearer.

Comment: @MDMarra gotcha... I didn't read the entire thread... but just wanted to clarify lol. Deploying win7 as a web server for example would end disastrous! (but then again, I wouldn't even deploy M$ Server with IIS for a webserver -- I'm all about the LAMP stack - Red Hat FTW!) lol

Comment: `but then again, I wouldn't even deploy M$ Server with IIS for a webserver` - Heh, it's funny that you say that on a Stack Exchange site. The entire Stack Exchange network is IIS, MSSQL Server, and .NET. There is Linux in the cache and load balancing tier, but all of the actual data is served and presented from Windows.

Comment: @MDMarra I didn't see your comment until now... funny. My company's web host provider (we're in distribution b2b) is a complete M$ shop too. I'm just saying, my first choice is and for the forseeable future will always be Linux for anything that's critical. There's a reason 9 of the top 10 supercomputers run Linux instead of windows ;-P

Answer (score 2):

I use **[Ericom Blaze](http://www.ericom.com/ericom_blaze.asp)** as a low-latency RDP accelerator solution for my personal systems. I've also deployed it in situations where I needed full-screen or multiple-monitor RDP to a remote site. One clear example was having financial traders in Chicago who needed to run a GUI app in a co-located system in Toronto. Ericom's protocol was very efficient for this task.

They have a [larger suite](http://www.ericom.com/citrix_alternative.asp) built around the protocol to serve as a lower-cost Citrix alternative .

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that RDP is probably among the best remote desktop software out there, and it happens to be built into all versions of windows pro. Much better than VNC as far as reliability and ease-of-use go.

Comment: i also tried that but the audio is still bad